epoll_wait hangs after a large write to a dead process' non-blocking pipe returns EAGAIN
Scenario:

A subprocess is started, its stdin and stdout are attached to the parent process
SIGPIPE is blocked to prevent erroring out when the subprocess dies (sigtimedwait is used to clear the signal)
Soon the subprocess is killed with -9 (it's a dedicated test)
The parent writes 1MB to the subprocess' stdin, which - in some cases - hangs. The issue becomes much more pronounces if the CPU is loaded (e.g. by stress -c 96). A race condition, yay!

It looks like the difference between the successful and the hung runs is this:
Successful runs: write attempt fails with errno=EPIPE, which is then handled
Failed runs: the first 64K are written successfully (presumably filling the buffer), next write returns -1 with errno=EAGAIN, then epoll_wait is called with EPOLLOUT without a timeout (to wait for the buffer to clear under normal circumstances) - AND it never returns
I tried:

Adding EPOLLHUP and EPOLLERR that should trigger regardless
Adding EPOLLRDHUP which was promising, but achieved nothing
Checking that the process is alive right before calling epoll_wait, but it's always shown as alive (tried both kill(pid, 0) and waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)). Plus, it  would still be racy anyway
Checking sigtimedwait's output - it returns -1 with errno=EAGAIN (sadly no EPIPE as I could handle that)
Switching to level-triggered, assuming something was getting lost due to re-arming the relevant events. No change.

Note 1: This seems to be an epoll's quirk, and if so - I'd appreciate a recommended workaround
Note 2: I have a solution that works around the hang, but I'm not sure it's a great one - so will hold off sharing it to not skew the answers

Are you sure the child hasn't become a zombie?

If waitpid() isn't reaping the child, it's not really dead. Do you see it in ps, and what is its state?

We're more likely to be able to make a diagnosis and / or good suggestions for mitigation if you provide a [mre] with which the problem can be reproduced.  At least intermittently.

What about calling epoll_wait with a semi-large timeout (e.g. 5 seconds) that guarantees that if a timeout occurs, things are abnormal? Then, treat this as you would EPIPE?

Semi frame challenge: it would be typical in a situation such as you describe to interpret reaching EOF on the pipe from child to parent as indicating that the child had terminated. Is there some reason to not interpret it that way in your case, so that it makes sense to try to write more data to the child after reaching that EOF?

Please edit your question and post your code. Not getting an EPIPE might occur if, given a pipe from parent to child, the parent did not close the input side of the pipe. This would interfere with normal EOF, etc. This may not be occurring, but a second pair of eyes might help.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.
I can't post an example as it's a part of a large codebase and it would take a lot of time to distill it to something I could post.
I also can't easily see the process' status as it's only observed on a remote machine that gets deleted right away.
Regarding calling epoll_wait with a longish timeout - that's my workaround, but it might introduce a race of its own due to rearming, won't it? I'd love to get to the issue's root cause if possible.
Regarding EOF - the read is not guaranteed to happen in prod, it's just part of the test :-(

@Barmar, I just realized that yes - the child process must be a zombie as the logic runs between it getting SIGKILL and waitpid being called (which happens right after the hung write) by the parent. FWIW, there's no SIGCHLD handling due to the implementation's peculiarities, and the test simulates a flow when the subprocess (not controlled by us) dies/is killed unexpectedly (e.g. by OOM) while we're trying to communicate with it - so it being a zombies is kinda expected at this stage...
